# Altium Gerber export fails

Tags: pcb, altium

I have a circuit I did in Altium.  I did auto trace; everything looks good but when it's converted to Gerber it shows a lot of weird marks and traces.  So I went back and undid all the traces and made a Gerber of just the plain ICs on the board. Like this image:

[image: Circuit as it should be]

But the Gerber moves things around like this:

[image: What Gerber gives me]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please include: Altium version, the steps you took to create the Gerber files, and how you are viewing the Gerber files.

Comment: Your origins are not set up correctly. Make sure to set your relative origin and make sure all of your gerber layers are referenced to the relative origin.

Comment: @DerStrom8 i am not sure its an origin issue. if you look all the way to the right, it cuts the top right 2 IC's in half. Half is shown correctly and the right half of the ic is not there. If it was an origin issue you would think the whole IC would be gone not just half?

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I am using version 15.  To create i followed an online guide.  First i make a cam file, (looks good ) then export to gerber.  to view i view gerber files in same program altium.

Comment: Need more details.  A common mistake is to export gerbers from the Camtastic interface.  One does not need to do this.  I'll add details in an answer section below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

[Exporting fabrication files (gerber) in Altium leads to wrong connections](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328707/exporting-fabrication-files-gerber-in-altium-leads-to-wrong-connections)

for a possible solution.

Quoted below:

> When you view the files in Camtastic, you are already viewing the
>   Gerber files. Camtastic is a "Gerber File Viewer and Editor".
>
> **You do not need to export anything from Camtastic.**
>
> After you generate the Gerber files (typically done using an 'OutJob'
>   file), simply open the output folder in your project files (using
>   windows explorer), and zip up the output files you need to send to
>   your pcb manufacturer.
>
> You can use Camtastic to view the generated Gerber files, and
>   pseudo-independently confirm that they are ok and conform to some
>   rules (see the Camtastic analysis menu).
>
> Sometimes, in rare and advanced circumstances, one would want to edit
>   Gerber data using Camtastic, and re-export using the tools in
>   Camtastic program. However, this is really unusual now-a-days, and I
>   have not had the need in a decade.
>
> Camtastic can be used as part of the process to reverse engineer
>   Gerber data back to a pcb file. But this also is an advanced and
>   unusual requirement.
>
> 'OutJobs' are your friends. You'll be happier if you use them.

Comment: I did as you said, but before you posted I also re did the pcb layout , setting all origins again.  Doing this , with also what you said has fixed the issue. Thanks.